# Array not displaying anything when called inside another variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple array which has been used before with no problems. Now I am trying to use it again and it is displaying nothing for text (Even in view source).

Array:

```
$month = Array(
    1 => "January",
    2 => "February",
    3 => "March",
    4 => "April",
    5 => "May",
    6 => "June",
    7 => "July",
    8 => "August",
    9 => "September",
    10 => "October",
    11 => "November",
    12 => "December"
);
```

Code:

```
function getMonthlyStats($comic_id) {
    require "config.php";
    $query = 'SELECT *, SUM(views) AS `views` FROM '.$db_tbl_stats.' WHERE '.$db_fld_stats_comic_id.'="'.$comic_id.'" GROUP BY '.$db_fld_stats_month.' ASC';
    $r_query = mysql_query($query);
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)) {
    $percent = ($result[$db_fld_stats_views]/getTotalStats($comic_id))*100;
    $m = number_format($result['month']);
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width="100">&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo $month[$m];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td width="400" class="bar"><div style="width: '.$percent.'%"></div>'.$result[$db_fld_stats_views].' Views</td>';
        echo '<td>'.number_format($percent).'%</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

}
```

$m returns a number from 1-12 which obviously represents a month.

If you need more info I will be happy to explain more. Any help is greatly appreciated! Going on 4 hours writing and my eyes are tired.

Comment: can you please provide more code?

Comment: `var_dump($m)` returns `string(1) "7"`

Comment: do a `var_dump` of `$month` also, it may be overridden somewhere.

Comment: `var_dump($month)` returns `null`

Comment: There's your problem. Make $month global or pass it in an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `global $month;` to your function, or use `$GLOBALS['month']` instead of `$month`.

This is called "variable scope". See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for more details.

Comment: yeah $m comes out as either 7 or 8 atm as those are the only 2 i have in my database.

Comment: What happens if you add the line `print $month[7]`?

Comment: `print $m;` returns a 7 or 8.

Comment: Sure - what about `print $month[7];` or `print $month[8];`?

Comment: `print $month[7]` = nothing displayed.

Comment: Beautiful!!! thank you for the time and link! I totally forgot about that lol. Much Appreciated!

Comment: Tick the happy green box, now ;-)

Comment: yeah there was a time limit :D had 38 seconds left to accept on my last click lol! you are green now!